# Unreal Engine Ubuntu: Failed to import video, unknown file extension

Tags: unreal-4, linux, file-format, video

I've been reading tutorials and guides on getting video file playback in Unreal. I have media player materials created and textures. I'm having issues importing video files to Content/Movies directory. When I use the import manager the files don't show. Drag and drop says its an unknown file extension for MP4, MWV, and other formats I tried like AVI even though I know AVI is not supported. So I wonder if maybe I'm missing a plugin for Unreal 4.8 / 4.9 in Linux?

Comment: You should be asking this on the support forums for the Unreal Engine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on the support forums for the Unreal Engine.